# Magento 2 "we can't find products matching the selection" page cache invalidates

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

*Update: I believe this issue may have been caused by a crossover between the cron:run & indexer:reindex cron jobs running every minute, I have changed the reindex job to run every hour instead of every minute and so far the FPC has not invalidated*

Magento 2.1.7 installation

Cron jobs set to run every minute (`cache clear, reindex` etc)
Using either built-in or Varnish (TTL attribute removed from XML due to disappearing navbar)

It seems that the something is causing the "**no products**" message regardless of whether the `full page cache` is enabled or disabled, as soon as the cache is cleared (manually or by cron) then the products will reappear upon refresh.

But it is not good for the customers to be browsing pages and then be shown an empty page.

The cache is invalidating regardless of whether changes are made to the catalog or not. Perhaps one of the other cron jobs is invalidating the cache?

List of cron jobs:

```
/public_html/update/cron.php > /dev/null
/public_html/bin/magento cron:run > /dev/null   
/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex > /dev/null     
/public_html/bin/magento cache:clean > /dev/null    
/public_html/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /dev/null
```

Hoping someone has suffered a similar issue with a fix

RM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue with Magento2

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8189

Still an open issue am afraid :(

Comment: Thank you very much, hopefully that will be resolved soon!

Comment: Please include the release this bug would have been fixed in, so that people know if this issue no longer applies to their situation.